# woocommerce pages without content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qttDu.png)I have a problem with default WooCommerce pages having no content. My friend said that index.php is the problem because it only has get_header and get_footer. But I still can't figure out what to do with the index

I tried using shortcodes but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Look add document body class wbat template it is, then in template check if there is the_content() alose check if this not wraped in condition check if sthis not empty, wc runing shorcode in main content area to display its template, but yif you not running the_content() you cant get that wc template displayed.

Comment: Have you put content in these pages?

Comment: no i did not post content on these pages mr ahmad and mr beneris answer is not clear to me, i will try to google what you were talking about